# "Stop a loophole" vs. "fix a loophole"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, collocation

Which is the preferred usage — "to stop a loophole" or "to fix a loophole"?

Comment: "It is time to **fix** a loophole in Alabama law that allows people with severe mental illness to purchase firearms." http://timesdaily.com/stories/Firearms-loophole,201132

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither. The verb you are looking for is *close*.

Just to demonstrate that that's what people actually use, here are the stats from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and the [British National Corpus (BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/):

```
                      COCA    BNC

[close] a loophole     23      3
[plug] a loophole       4      1
[stop] a loophole       0      0
[fix] a loophole        0      0
```

And for the sake of completeness, here's a list of the top 25 collocations from both corpora for `[v*] a loophole`:

```
             COCA                          BNC

 1    FOUND A LOOPHOLE     23     BE A LOOPHOLE         3
 2    IS A LOOPHOLE        16     IS A LOOPHOLE         3
 3    CLOSE A LOOPHOLE     15     FIND A LOOPHOLE       3
 4    'S A LOOPHOLE        11     EXPLOITING A LOOPHOLE 2 
 5    WAS A LOOPHOLE        9     HAVE A LOOPHOLE       2
 6    FIND A LOOPHOLE       9     CLOSE A LOOPHOLE      2
 7    CLOSING A LOOPHOLE    5     SAYS A LOOPHOLE       2
 8    CREATED A LOOPHOLE    4     USING A LOOPHOLE      1
 9    EXPLOITED A LOOPHOLE  4     SAY A LOOPHOLE        1
10    PLUG A LOOPHOLE       4     PLUG A LOOPHOLE       1
11    USED A LOOPHOLE       3     LEAVES A LOOPHOLE     1
12    LEFT A LOOPHOLE       3     CLAIMS A LOOPHOLE     1
13    EXPLOITING A LOOPHOLE 3     BECOMING A LOOPHOLE   1
14    FINDING A LOOPHOLE    3     CREATE A LOOPHOLE     1
15    CLOSES A LOOPHOLE     3     CLOSING A LOOPHOLE    1
16    DISCOVERED A LOOPHOLE 3   
17    CREATING A LOOPHOLE   2   
18    CONTAIN A LOOPHOLE    2   
19    ADDRESS A LOOPHOLE    2   
20    CREATE A LOOPHOLE     2   
21    HAVE A LOOPHOLE       2   
22    HAS A LOOPHOLE        2   
23    OPEN A LOOPHOLE       2   
24    USE A LOOPHOLE        2   
25    SUPPORTED A LOOPHOLE  2   
26    USING A LOOPHOLE      2   
27    LEAVE A LOOPHOLE      2
```

As you can see, out of all the various things that various people like to do to various loopholes in various situations, only *close* and *plug* fit the bill in yours.

Comment: *Plug* is more vivid, but I since the metaphorical sense is so oft-used as to stand as as a sense on its own, I think I would only use it in the sense of a physical loophole.

Answer (score 1):

[Reverso](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/loophole) suggests "*close* a loophole":

> → The government plans to close some 70 tax loopholes used by companies.
> to close a loophole      combler une lacune
> → It's time we closed the loophole which allows criminals to gain easy access to lethal weapons

However, *plug*, *fix* and *stop* are also found, in that order.

Google results:

- "*close* a loophole" — about 1,080,000
- "*plug* a loophole" — about 230,000
- "*fix* a loophole" — about 153,000
- "*stop* a loophole" — about 9,540

Being an idiomatic expression, the choice of the word depends much on the context as well.